# Bundle Products not adding to the cart in magento1.9.1.0

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, addtocart, bundled-product, varnish

I am tackling with a strange problem in magento 1.9.1.0, the bundle products in my magento store are not being added to the cart instead when I click on the '**Add To Cart**' button it's showing-

> Error 503 Service Unavailable
>
> ```
>   Service Unavailable Guru Meditation:
>
>   XID: 2050290084
>
>   Varnish cache server
> ```

All the other types of products are working fine and being added to cart normally. 
There's a paypal checkout button on my product view page also which is also showing the same 503 error, so i checked the form but that just looks same as the others on simple or configurable products. When I used the same theme on localhost fresh installation it just worked fine and every product or even bundle product is being added to the cart.

I searched over internet regarding this error and implemented almost every way to resolve it, i disabled shopping cart rules, changed my bundle.xml with the default one, disabled other extensions, checked my view page but none of these helped.
 I have also installed Mgt Commerce Varnish in my magento, may be that's generating the error. Hence I am not much familiar with the varnish, so I am not so sure about that.

So please somebody help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this error finally. I just enabled the `error_display` and got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getPosition() on a non-object in htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Type.php on line 850

So I tried to solve this error, I looked in the `Type.php` file and their I removed `getOption()` from the line 850 as:

From:

```
$a->getOption()->getPosition()
```

to:

```
$a->getPosition()
```

After this I got other errors in the same file, for them I did exactly the same and removed `getOption()` from all the error lines. And this worked!